# Number of edges of polytope: what can be said?

Tags: geometry, convex-optimization, linear-programming, convex-geometry, polytopes

***Background:*** I am reading a paper ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02162)) that concerns linear programs (with unknown constraints).

If a linear program has constraints $\mathbf A \mathbf x \leq \mathbf b$, where $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$, and $\mathbf b \in \mathbb R^n$, then this paper defines a polytope $\mathcal P$ to be $\mathcal P := \left\{ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n \colon \mathbf A \mathbf x \leq \mathbf b \right\}$.

The paper uses the set of edges of $\mathcal P$, denoted by $E_{\mathcal P}$, and involves an algorithm that depends on the number of edges, written $\left\lvert E_{\mathcal P} \right\rvert$.

***Question:*** What can be said about the relationship between the dimensions related to the polytope, i.e. $m$ and $n$, and the number of edges, $\left\lvert E_{\mathcal P} \right\rvert$?

***My attempt:*** According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686562/understanding-mcmullens-upper-bound-theorem), by McMullen's Upper Bound Theorem, if the polytope has $V$ vertices, then we have

\begin{equation}
\left\lvert E_{\mathcal P} \right\rvert \leq \binom{V}{2}.
\end{equation}

According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127423/how-many-vertices-can-a-convex-polytope-have), the number of vertices $V$ will be bounded as follows:

\begin{equation}
V \leq \binom{m - \lceil n / 2 \rceil}{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor} + \binom{m - \lfloor n / 2 \rfloor - 1}{\lceil n / 2 \rceil - 1}.
\end{equation}

***Is this right?*** What else can be said? If the above is correct, are there books that contain these results? I have been looking at Chapters 15 and 17 of the Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498711391)), but I don't see these precise results in there.

Comment: The first inequality is obvious, is not it?

Comment: @user I don't know much about polytopes. If an edge, by definition, involves two vertices, then I guess you are right. But the correctness of, and reasoning for, the bound on $V$ is still not at all obvious to me, even after looking at the Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry that I mentioned.

Comment: Yes an edge connects always two vertices. But not any pair of vertices is connected by an edge. Consider a tetrahedron and a cube in 3D, both these bodies can be constructed in any dimension.